# `in` behavior in pandas.DataFrame.assign() method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda

Consider the simple string data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'strings': "qwe rty uio".split()
})

df
```

```
>>> df
  strings
0     qwe
1     rty
2     uio
```

Then, one wants to create column `t` by checking a substring "t" in `strings` column.

```py
df.assign(t = lambda obs: "t" in obs.strings)
```

Now one can see the result:

```
>>> df.assign(t = lambda obs: "t" in obs.strings)
  strings      t
0     qwe  False
1     rty  False
2     uio  False
```

The question is why one can see the wrong `t` value in observation with index `1`.

UPD:

No extra solutions needed.

Comment: ...what's the question?

Comment: The question is "why the wrong value of `df` in column `t` of observation `1`?"

Comment: Because `'t' in df['strings']` returns False, you are checking to see if a string is part of pd.Series.  This is not a valid comparison.  You need to either use list comprehension or the string accessor to get values from the pd.Series.

Comment: But `t = lambda obs: obs.strings + "ABC"` is working as `obs.strings` has a string type.

Comment: Nope.  do this instead, `df.assign(t = lambda x: type(x['strings']))` Look at your types. You, see x['strings'] is a pd.Series.

Comment: You are right! The value of variable `obs` has `Series` type and `obs.strings.to_string()` displays all the values of the entire column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to use a lambda and check if 't' exists in strings simply do:

```
df['t'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('t'))
```

result:

```
    strings    t
0   qwe        False
1   rty        True
2   uio        False
```

Edit: to use assing:

```
df.assign(t = lambda x: x['strings'].str.contains('t'))
```

Comment: Love it! The `apply()` method is working. The question is about `assign()` one.

Comment: @Ruben Kazumov check my edit. One things to note: you may confuse the 't' in front of the lambda (statement as column) and the 't'); minimize the confusion with proper column name :-) hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Use the follow, with the string accessor in pandas and contains:

```
df['strings'].str.contains('t')
```

Output:

```
0    False
1     True
2    False
Name: strings, dtype:
```

### Using df.assign

```
df.assign(t = df['strings'].str.contains('t'))
```

Output:

```
  strings      t
0     qwe  False
1     rty   True
2     uio  False
```

### Using list comprehension with 'in'

```
df.assign(tn = ['t' in i for i in df['strings']])
```

Output:

```
  strings     tn
0     qwe  False
1     rty   True
2     uio  False
```

Comment: It is excellent approach, but how about `assign()` method? The question is about DataFrame, but not Series object.

Comment: I love it! Can you add an approach with lambda and `in`?

Answer (score 1):

If you do want the `assign` , notice lambda in assign will not check each cell , it still check column based , that is why it show false for all

```
df.assign(t = df.strings.apply(lambda x : 't' in x))
  strings      t
0     qwe  False
1     rty   True
2     uio  False
```